# Qualcomm DSP: hexagon-sim with command line arguments

Tags: signal-processing, qualcomm, hexagonal-architecture, hexagon-dsp

I am profiling c code on a hexagon simulator with the following tool:

```
Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.5.3/tools/HEXAGON_Tools/8.3.07/Tools/bin/hexagon-sim --timing --profile binary.hexagon
```

The binary is built with the hexagon-clang:

```
Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.5.3/tools/HEXAGON_Tools/8.3.07/Tools/bin/hexagon-clang
```

I am, however, unable to pass command line arguments to my binary when running
hexagon-sim

Does anybody know how to do that?

I tried:

```
Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.5.3/tools/HEXAGON_Tools/8.3.07/Tools/bin/hexagon-sim --timing --profile binary.hexagon argument1 argument2
Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.5.3/tools/HEXAGON_Tools/8.3.07/Tools/bin/hexagon-sim --timing --profile binary.hexagon 'argument1 argument2'
Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.5.3/tools/HEXAGON_Tools/8.3.07/Tools/bin/hexagon-sim --timing --profile 'binary.hexagon argument1 argument2'
```

But that all just gives the error:

```
More than one non-option on command line!
(binary.hexagon)
(argument1)
Cannot determine executable - aborting.
```

Comment: Try` hexagon-sim --timing --profile binary.hexagon -- argument1 argument2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `--` for that.

Like so:

```
hexagon-sim --timing --profile binary.hexagon -- argument1 argument2
```

From "Hexagon Simulator User Guide", Qualcomm doc `80-N2040-17 P`:

> **Running the simulator**
> ...
> Command switches are used to control various
> simulator options. A switch consists of one or two dash characters
> followed by a switch name and optional parameter. Note that switch
> names are case-sensitive. Switches must be separated by at least one
> space. The command switch (`--`) when delimited by spaces on either
> side is used to separate the command arguments of the target
> application from those of the simulator. For example:
>
> ```
> hexagon-sim --rtos q.cfg a.out -- 10 // 10 is target app arg
> hexagon-sim --rtos q.cfg -- a.out 10 // alternate form
> ```